# PeekMessage() throws an unhandled exception (access violation)

Tags: c++, winapi

in my application i use the following code:

```
bool HandleMessages()
{
MSG msg;

if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
{
    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        return FALSE;

    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return true;
}
```

This is the standard code for message handling in windows i thought, but now when i try to run the program, i always get an Exception at the PeekMessage() call.

Exception message is

> Unhandled exception at 0x57a10eed
> (msvcr100d.dll) in testing.exe:
> 0xC0000005: access violation while
> reading at Position 0x6666665c.

Im completely lost here, cant see why it would throw an exception. Anyone got a hint?

Call Stack:

> msvcr100d.dll!__local_unwind2()  + 0x48 Bytes   Asm

> msvcr100d.dll!_except_handler3()  + 0xed Bytes  Asm

> Testing.exe!_except_handler4(_EXCEPTION_RECORD * ExceptionRecord, _EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD * EstablisherFrame, _CONTEXT * ContextRecord, void * DispatcherContext)  + 0x24 Bytes  C

> Testing.exe!_except_handler4(_EXCEPTION_RECORD * ExceptionRecord, _EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD * EstablisherFrame, _CONTEXT * ContextRecord, void * DispatcherContext)  + 0x24 Bytes  C

Disassembly:

> *continue*:

> 57CE0EEA  lea         esi,[esi+esi*2]
>
> 57CE0EED  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebx+esi*4]
> 57CE0EF0  mov         dword ptr [esp+0Ch],ecx
> 57CE0EF4  mov         dword ptr [eax+0Ch],ecx
> 57CE0EF7  cmp         dword ptr [ebx+esi*4+4],0
>
> 57CE0EFC  jne         _lu_continue (57CE0F15h)
>
> 57CE0EFE  push        101h
>
> 57CE0F03  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebx+esi*4+8]
> 57CE0F07  call        _NLG_Notify (57CE0F55h)
> 57CE0F0C  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebx+esi*4+8]
> 57CE0F10  call        _NLG_Call (57CE0F74h)

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete & actual code?

Comment: Yes, thats where VS2010 debugger stops and shows the exception

Comment: So you are calling HandleMessages() on a good object instance?

Comment: off-topic but please don't mix `BOOL` and `bool`.

Comment: Your "if (PeekMessage..." should probably be a "while (PeekMessage..." otherwise posted messages are going to queue up and may overflow the message queue, which can be very bad. -- At least, I am assuming there's no good reason that you are dispatching all sent messages and *at most* one posted message. In situations like this you normally want to either process all queued messages or none of them; almost never would you only want to process the first one and leave the others.

Comment: The call stack is useless. It's the call stack of the standard unhandled exception filter at the bottom of your code. Please set up Visual Studio to break, when the exception is *thrown*. You'll get a complete call stack from there.

Answer (score 1):

- Show us your call stack. If it's crashing in `msvcr100d.dll`, then it's happening outside of `PeekMessage` (before or after the call). you should have good debugging info for this.
- Take a look at the `this` pointer if applicable
- do a rebuild all
- Step into the disassembly

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the callstack you posted is quite sufficient to make anything out from it.

Is there a chance you could be calling HandleMessages() in response to a message? This could result in recursion / stack exhaustion.

Comment: A stack overflow wouldn't cause an access violation, though. Besides that, the pointer (`0x6666665c`) looks remarkably non-random, almost like someone injected some sort of magic value.

Comment: @IInspectable: Do you have a time machine or something?

Comment: Why would that be required?

Comment: Just wondering why you're commenting on an answer I posted nearly 8 years ago :)

Comment: Age doesn't impact visibility. This answer is still visible to anyone coming to this site, and I feel it doesn't match the question. I leave comments on contributions that are 8 years old for the same reason I leave comments on documentation that is likely older: To ask for clarification on publicly visible content.